# Combination of Singleton class and volatile variable

Tags: java, multithreading

As far as I know, volatile variables will be always read and written from the main memory. Then I think about the Singleton class. Here is how my program is:

1. Singleton class

```
public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton sin;
    private static volatile int count;
    static{
        sin = new Singleton();
        count = 0;
    }
    private Singleton(){

    }
    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        return sin;
    }

    public String test(){
        count++;
        return ("Counted increased!" + count);
    }

}
```

2. Main class

```
public class Java {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived d1 = new Derived("d1");
        d1.start();
        Derived d2 = new Derived("d2");
        d2.start();
        Derived d3 = new Derived("d3");
        d3.start();

    }
;

}

class Derived extends Thread {

    String name;
    public Derived(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void run() {
        Singleton a = Singleton.getInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Current thread: "+ name + a.test());
        }
    }
}
```

I know this maybe a dumb question, but i'm not good at multithreading in Java thus this problem confuses me a lot. I thought the `static volatile int count` variable in Singleton class will always have the latest value, but apparently it does not... 

Can someone help me to understand this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well what are you seeing, compared with what you expected to see? (I'd use AtomicInteger in this case, btw... currently your increment is still a read/modify/write cycle, which isn't thread-safe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `volatile` has nothing to do with thread synchronization. Even though the read from `static volatile int count` would indeed always return the latest value, multiple threads may write the same new value back into it.

Consider this scenario with two threads:

```
count is initialized zero
Thread A reads count, sees zero
Thread B reads count, sees zero
Thread A advances count to 1, stores 1
Thread B advances count to 1, stores 1
Thread A writes "Counted increased! 1"
Thread B writes "Counted increased! 1"
```

Both threads read the latest value, but since `++` is not an atomic operation, once the read is complete, each thread is on its own. Both threads independently compute the next value, and then store it back into the `count` variable. The net effect is that a variable is incremented once, even though both threads performed the increment.

If you would like to increment an `int` from multiple threads, use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: OhI see, can I understand that volatile variable should be used in single thread program only ?

Comment: @Xitrum `volatile` is useful in in multithreaded programs, too - for example, when one thread modifies the data, and the other thread needs to read the data. For example, a `boolean` flag that indicates to a thread that it needs to exit is commonly made `volatile`.

Comment: "synchronization" is a broad term, and `volatile` does provide a kind of synchronization.  The problem here is that the program needs _mutual exclusion_ which is a different kind of synchronization.  I wish I had some of what the Java designers were smoking when they decided to use `synchronized` as the name of the keyword that provides mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet indicated, it would be best if you use `AtomicInteger`. Using volatile variables reduces the risk of memory consistency errors, but it doesn't eliminate the need to synchronize atomic action.

I think this modification would help with your problem.

```
public synchronized String test(){
    count++;
    return ("Counted increased!" + count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reader threads are not doing any locking and until writer thread comes out of synchronized block, memory will not be synchronized and value of 'sin' will not be updated in main memory. both threads reads the same values and thus updates it by adding one, if you want to resolve make test method synchronised.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html#ixzz3PGYRMtgE